# Zend Framework route/redirect

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to redirect the user to a registered page once they have registered but its not doing so..

```
<?php

class RegisterController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $form = new Application_Form_Register();
        $form->submit->setLabel('Register');
        $this->view->form = $form;
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
                $first_name = $form->getValue('first_name');
                $surname = $form->getValue('surname');
                $email = $form->getValue('email');
                $username = $form->getValue('username');
                $password = $form->getValue('password');
                $is_admin = $form->getValue('is_admin');
                $age = $form->getValue('age');
                $gender = $form->getValue('gender');
                $uni = $form->getValue('uni');
                $register = new Application_Model_DbTable_Users();
                $register->addUser($first_name, $surname, $email, $username, $password, $is_admin, $age, $gender, $uni);

            } else {
                $form->populate($formData);
            }
            $route = array('controller'=>'Register', 'action'=>'registered');
                    $this->_helper->redirector->gotoRoute($route);

        }
    }

    public function registeredAction()
    {
        // action body
    }

}
```

This is what I have

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller you can to the following:

```
$this->_redirect('/controller/action');
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually don't use `gotoRoute()` therefore I am not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but your controller-name should be all lowercased, i.e. `Register` should be `register` or maybe `gotoRouteAndExit()` will solve your problem (just picked it up from a quick glance at the [API](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/))

You could try an alternative: For routing between actions/controllers I find the following most convenient:

```
$this->_helper->redirector('registered');
```

Which will redirect you to registeredAction in the same controller. If you want to go to an action in a different controller, just add the controller as 2nd argument like this:

```
$this->_helper->redirector('registered', 'register');
```